# Remove certain string parts in PHP with regex

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to remove certain parts of my string using `preg_match`. I do not know if this is the best scenario.

I have the following string:

```
Uploaded Today 13:11, Size 117.09 MiB, ULed by demonoidt
```

I want to get only the `117.09` part of the string. I am using `preg_match` like this:

```
$res = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string);
```

But this will return all the numbers found in the string, so I would have something like:

```
131111709
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you and happy holidays.

Comment: The quickest way to end up with 117.09 would be `$var = "117.09"` This is obviously not what you meant, but i can think of any number of substring operations that would only work for this case. Could you clarify why you want that part?

Comment: do you want to extract 117.09 from the string?

Comment: It will never be the same, the information is stored in an array. that whole uploaded... and so on so it will not be just 117.09, that can change easily so that is why I went for the preg_replace at the first time, to find just the numbers in that string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using a *matching* approach rather than the *replacing* one.

Use

```
/([\d.]+)\s*MiB/
```

Or, if the `Size` word is always before the number, then use

```
/Size\s*([\d.]+)/
```

and grab Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/obDKWM/1) (or [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/obDKWM/2)).

**Pattern details**:

- `([\d.]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits or `.`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `MiB` - a sequence of literal chars.

NOTE that you may make the number matching  part more precise by replacing `[\d.]+` with `\d*\.?\d+`.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/cDygyk):

```
$re = '/([\d.]+)\s*MiB/';
$str = 'Uploaded Today 13:11, Size 117.09 MiB, ULed by demonoidt';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
  echo $match[1]; // => 117.09
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also -

```
$s = 'Uploaded Today 13:11, Size 117.09 MiB, ULed by demonoidt';

preg_match('/\d*\.\d*/', $s, $match);

var_dump($match[0]);
```

**Output**

```
string(6) "117.09"
```

> \d* matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

[Test](https://eval.in/705536)

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by following regex:

```
$re = '/(?<=Size )(\d.)+/';
$str = 'Uploaded Today 13:11, Size 117.09 MiB, ULed by demonoidt';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
  echo $match[0]; // => 117.09
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> @Cristian Badea if you want to extract particular part of string like
>   117.09 from your string so you can also get this by the php string function

try the below strpos, substr function to get your 117.09 string from the whole string

```
<?php
    $a = "Uploaded Today 13:11, Size 117.09 MiB, ULed by demonoidt";
    $extract = "117.09";
    if(strpos($a, $extract)){
        $b = substr($a, strpos($a, $extract), strlen($extract));
        echo $b;
    }
?>
```

In $b you will get your 117.09 part of string (y)

Comment: I need to be dynamic so I will never have 117.09 ... and the entire string is generated automatically, so I will have to get the size part.

Comment: How come this is an accepted answer? The `117.09` is a value to be extracted, it is not known beforehand. Its length is not known either, it can be `30`, or `5`.